# Logstash Input Plugin - Use Python script

Tags: python, input, plugins, logstash

I'm currently testing Logstash and got interested in the input plugin development but I'm hitting a wall and need help.

Here is my problem : I have a python script that takes about 10/15 seconds to run and returns a json string which I'd like to capture from the stdout.

So I call my script from the logstash input plugin and to do that, I use the following code :

```
Open3.popen3("python", "/path/to/myscript.py", "--param1",  @param1_value, "--param2", @param2_value) do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    puts stdout.read
end
```

When I call my script from my Logstash input plugin and try to execute the "bundle exec rspec" command, I receive the following error :

```
Failure/Error: DEFAULT_FAILURE_NOTIFIER = lambda { |failure, _opts| raise failure }
   expected `#<Thread:0x46678e49 sleep>.alive?` to return false, got true
```

I noticed that if my script just output a "Hello world" everything works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading me.